# Preventing user checkout with observer on sales_order_place_before event

Tags: magento2, checkout

When trying to stop checkout process with observer on 'sales_order_place_before' event, process is stopped but observer Exception doesn't show up,  rather 
**Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement** message is showing up ('Unable to place order. Please try again later.')

Is it possible to have observer's message or at least both?

```
public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $this->_logger->debug('SingleVendorOrderObs:sales_order_place_before');

    /** @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
    $order = $observer->getOrder();

    $cartVendors = [];
    foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $cartVendors[] = $item->getUdropshipVendor();
    }

    if(count($cartVendors) > 1) {
        /* dev debug */
        $this->_logger->debug('cnt: ' . count($cartVendors) . ' vendors: ' . json_encode($cartVendors));

        throw new LocalizedException(__("You can't order items from multiple vendors! "));
        // override savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this code for exeption generation in event observer.

```
if(count($cartVendors) > 1) 
{
    $message = "You can't order items from multiple vendors!";
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($message));
    return;
}
```

Comment: No it is not working, still getting 'Unable to place order. Please try again later.' which comes from savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder() later on in chain.

Comment: Have your code get $cartVendors count > 1?

Comment: Yes, code gets into IF, and exception gets thrown, thing is that it is suppressed and next exception gets shown, which happens on savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()

Comment: Can you try to replace "return" to "exit" in above code.

Comment: Nothing changes. If I change Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php at line 71 throw new CouldNotSaveException(__($e->getMessage() . 'Unable to place order. Please try again later.'), $e); with "$e->getMessage()" I can get the previous error but it is really a wrong way to do it.

Comment: You don't need to return anything while throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a try/catch in `\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement`

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

If you want the real exception message to come through, you would need to remove the try/catch.

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    //try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    // } catch (\Exception $e) {
    //     throw new CouldNotSaveException(
    //         __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
    //         $e
    //     );
    // }
    return $orderId;
}
```